# How to set ulimit in chroot with --userspec

Tags: bash, chroot

I have script to create a minimal chroot (below), but I can't figure out how to get ulimit to work on the chroot'ed process:

```
#!/bin/bash

user=$1
apps="$2"
cmd_to_run="$3"
shift 3

directory="minimal_chroot"

if [ ! -d "$directory" ]; then
    mkdir -pv $directory/etc >/dev/null 2>&1

    grep /etc/passwd -e "^$user" | sed "s/\/home\/$user/\//" >> $directory/etc/passwd
    grep /etc/group -e "^$user" >> $directory/etc/group

    mkdir -p "$directory/etc/security/" >/dev/null
    limits="$directory/etc/security/limits.conf"
    echo "$user hard nofile 100" >> $limits

    # cmds can be a space-separated list of commands
    for app in $apps; do
        file_path=`which $app`
        if [ -n "$file_path" ] ; then
            non_root_path=`echo "$file_path" | sed -E 's/^\/(.*$)/\1/'`
            mkdir -pv $directory/`dirname $non_root_path` >/dev/null 2>&1
            cp -v {,$directory}$file_path >/dev/null 2>&1

            for file in `ldd $file_path | grep "/lib" | sed -E 's/^.*[ \t]\/(lib[^ ]+\.[0-9]) .*$/\1/'` ; do
                mkdir -p $directory/`dirname $file | sed -E 's/^\/(.*$)/\1/'` >/dev/null 2>&1
                cp -v {,$directory}/$file >/dev/null 2>&1
            done
        fi
    done
fi

find $directory -maxdepth 1 -type f -exec rm {} + >/dev/null 2>&1

chmod -R o+rwx $directory >/dev/null 2>&1
find $directory -exec chmod o+rx-w {} + >/dev/null 2>&1
chmod o+rw $directory >/dev/null 2>&1

uid=`id -u $user`

ulimit -Su 10
sudo chroot --userspec=$uid:$uid $directory $cmd_to_run $* <&0 &
chroot_pid=$!

trap "kill -INT $chroot_pid" SIGINT SIGTERM SIGXCPU

wait $python_chroot_pid

find $directory -maxdepth 1 -type f -exec rm {} + >/dev/null 2>&1
```

Output:

```
blah@dev:~$ sudo ./minimal_chroot.sh chrootuser "ls cd pwd cat bash" bash
bash-4.2$ pwd
/
bash-4.2$ ulimit -a
core file size          (blocks, -c) 0
data seg size           (kbytes, -d) unlimited
scheduling priority             (-e) 0
file size               (blocks, -f) unlimited
pending signals                 (-i) 7806
max locked memory       (kbytes, -l) 64
max memory size         (kbytes, -m) unlimited
open files                      (-n) 1024
pipe size            (512 bytes, -p) 8
POSIX message queues     (bytes, -q) 819200
real-time priority              (-r) 0
stack size              (kbytes, -s) 8192
cpu time               (seconds, -t) unlimited
max user processes              (-u) 7806
virtual memory          (kbytes, -v) unlimited
file locks                      (-x) unlimited
bash-4.2$
```

notice that max user processes is still at 7806 instead of the 10 that I was trying to specify with the `ulimit -Su 10` command. Oh, I was also messing with `/etc/security/limits.conf` as can be seen with the `echo "$user hard nofile 100" >> $limits` line. This also is not taking effect.

How can I get ulimits to take effect while still keeping the chroot to a minimum?

### Attempt #2

I attempted to swap out this line:

```
sudo chroot --userspec=$uid:$uid $directory $cmd_to_run $* <&0 &
```

for this:

```
sudo chroot $directory bash -c "ulimit -Su 20; su $user; $cmd_to_run $*" <&0 &
```

This actually worked well, and `ulimit -a` showed the max user processes to be 20, but then I realized that it didn't `su` to `$user` and was still running as root, since I took out the --userspec.

Answer (score 1):

Notice that limits are enforced via a PAM module, namely [`pam_limits`](http://linux.die.net/man/8/pam_limits), and its configuration file is `/etc/security/limits.conf` by default, but simply putting that configuration file inside the `chroot` does not provide any real infrastructure.

The output of `ulimit -a` you are seeing is that of the `blah` user, which is logged in.

The `chroot` invocation does not trigger the PAM configuration at any point, and therefore it can't set any limits inside the `chroot`.

Comment: hmm, I've thought about adding bash to the chroot regardless of the apps passed in, and then running `bash -c "ulimit -Su 10 ; $cmd` in the chroot, but I was hoping to not have to include bash or sh at all. Is there a way to force the PAM configuration to trigger?

Comment: also, wouldn't the `ulimit -a` be the ulimit of root since I ran the script with sudo? Maybe my understanding is off on this point.